# Make timeline-chart out of .csv data

Tags: python, csv

```
for item in list_of_dictionaries:
    print(item['created_time']
```

I have a list of 70k dictionaries and each dict has the above key and the value is in this format:

```
Wed Sep 20 23:40:58 +0000 2017
```

What i need is to make a dictionarythat would tell me the number of entries for every hour in each day, such as:

for Tue:

```
[00:200,01:231,02 ... ]
```

Is there any way to convert that string ( Wed Sep 20 23:40:58 2017) into a datetime format so i could group them for every half an hour?

Comment: You want to use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) specifically with format: `'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'`, however you should consider using `pandas` to do the conversion as it will be quicker to do the conversion using `pandas.to_datetime`. Can you show what you've tried as it's a little unclear what you're really trying to achieve

Comment: it only works if i use string.replace('+0000 ','') on the dateformat time. Still a good suggestion, thx very much

Comment: I have 70k tweets with this format and i want to make a chart out of the data. I will group them by hours using pandas and then put the info on the chart using Plotly